# Connect via RDP as if it was a local session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

*Windows (10 / Server 2012 R2):*

Some applications behave differently, depending on the type of session. Some wouldn't even start in an RDP session.

Is there any possibility to manipulate the RDP-session in a way, so that those picky applications would take it as local?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Remote Desktop into Admin/Console session](http://superuser.com/questions/991691/windows-10-remote-desktop-into-admin-console-session)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/991740/393570) the `/console` switch has been removed.

All sessions should be treated the same as a physical log on. The [technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/01/04/mstsc-exe-no-more-console-switch-in-rdc-6-1/) article suggests using the `/admin` switch instead. Unfortunately I am not able to test this in my environment.

---

**Original answer**

When you run the RDC application you can add a switch to the command line to open it in console mode. This emulates the connection as if you were physically in front of the machine.

The command to run is:

```
mstsc /console
```

**Reference:** [Connect to the console session of a server using Remote Desktop for Administration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc775475%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The `/console` option seems not to be existent in my Windows 10 `mstsc`.   Adding the suggested option does not seem to change anything about the session type. The target-system is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Ah, interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before when using software that required a license dongle.  I will note the vendor we worked with eventually fixed this issue and sent us updated dongles, so we didn't' need this workaround anymore.  I believe it was Windows Server 2012 as well.

In order to create a "local" RDP session, try creating a Remote Assistance Invitation as a file.  It can be emailed or saved, and when you want to connect to the RDP session, open the invitation file to connect and type the *session password*.  You must enable Remote Assistance in Windows.

To [Enable Remote Assistance](https://www.hammer-software.com/how-to-enable-remote-assistance-and-allow-access-through-the-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-using-group-policy/):

> **Turning on Remote Access using Group Policy**
>
> 1. Edit an existing Group Policy object or create a new one using the
>    Group Policy Management Tool.
> 2. Expand the Computer Configuration/Policies/Software
>    Settings/Administrative Templates/System/Remote Assistance node and
>    open the Offer Remote Assistance rule.
> 3. Check the Enabled radio button. Under Options: select Allow helpers
>    to remotely control the computer from the drop down list. Click the
>    Show… button.
> 4. Enter the users or groups you want to have permissions to offer
>    Remote Assistance, one per line. Then click OK.
> 5. Click the OK button to exit and save the new setting.
> 6. Make sure the Group Policy Object is applied to the relevant
>    computers using the Group Policy Management Tool.
>
> **Allowing access through the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security using Group Policy**
>
> 1. Edit an existing Group Policy object or create a new one using the
>    Group Policy Management Tool.
> 2. Expand the Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security
>    Settings/Windows Firewall with Advanced Security/Windows Firewall
>    with Advanced Security/Inbound Rules node.
> 3. Check the Predefined: radio button and select Remote Assistance from
>    the drop down list. Click Next
> 4. Check the Remote Assistance rules for the Domain Profile and click
>    Next.
> 5. Check the Allow the Connection radio botton and click Finish to exit
>    and save the new rule.
> 6. Make sure the Group Policy Object is applied to the relevant
>    computers using the Group Policy Management Tool.

To generate the invitation (from the machine you want to connect to):

1. Type "msra" from the Run prompt
2. At the prompt, select "Invite someone you trust to help you"
3. Then select "Save this invitation as a file"
4. Note the password from the next screen, "Give your helper the invitation file and *session password*".

**To connect from a remote location**, open the invitation file and type in the *session password*.

I'm not sure if an invitation can be generated in an RDP session.  When we set this up, someone with admin priveleges was in the office to start the session, and we would keep it running for as long as possible.  I think I read somewhere there is an expiration date of 99 days?

If you don't have an admin that can setup the invitation locally, you could try [RDP Shadowing](https://www.urtech.ca/2014/01/solved-how-can-i-shadow-a-remote-desktop-terminal-services-user-in-server-2012/), but I have not tried this myself and it doesn't seem like it would give you any more "locality" than the RDP session you started with.

Lastly, you may need to apply [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/you-can-t-offer-remote-assistance-to-another-user-when-you-use-a-mandatory-profile-in-windows-8-1-or-windows-server-2012-r2-e11912cc-c743-3db1-6138-1b79d0569e28) update in Windows Server 2012 to use Remote Assistance.